# CSV type error, csv_reader not callable? Wont work

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

I am trying to write a set of code that displays a csv files contents. It was working last time and i saved it now i have opened it and it wont work? file is in the same directory and same name as before. I am getting this error: TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

```
   import csv
   with open('movehubqualityoflife.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
         csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

         for line in csv_reader:
             print(line)
```

Comment: Is this indentation correct? the line `csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)` should be indented by one level so that `csv_file` is in scope

Comment: Yeah it is sorry its just the way the code transferred over

Comment: Then that line should be indented by 1 level in

Comment: Indention is correct, i will edit question

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would i get the first ten data entries of the file? ignoring the first line which is : 'City', 'Movehub Rating', 'Purchase Power', 'Health Care', 'Pollution', 'Quality of Life', 'Crime Rating'

Comment: Using pandas would be trivial `import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv(r'movehubqualityoflife.csv', nrows=10)` you should look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct and I have tested it on a random csv file I had available. I would try creating a copy of the file, deleting the original and renaming the copy to `movehubqualityoflife.csv`. Hopefully, this would do the trick.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would i get the first ten data entries of the file? ignoring the first line which is : 'City', 'Movehub Rating', 'Purchase Power', 'Health Care', 'Pollution', 'Quality of Life', 'Crime Rating'

Comment: Use `next()` to skip the header and then an if condition to break the loop after printing the first 10 lines: 

`with open("movehubqualityoflife.csv", 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)

    line_counter = 1














    for line in csv_reader:
        
        if line_counter < 11:
            print(line)
        else:
            break
        line_counter += 1
`
But honestly, it would me much easier to do if you use `pandas`, as was mentioned in the comments section under your question.

Comment: hi, getting an invalid syntax error at break line_counter += 1, cant seem to figure out why

Comment: double check the indentation. line_counter += 1 should be on the new line indented on the same level as the if statement.

Comment: such a school boy error sorry lol thank you for all your help working fine now!